# Getting error while pushing Solr Metrics to Ganglia

Tags: solr, solrcloud, ganglia

I am new to Solr and trying to push solr metrics to Ganglia.
I have modified solr.xml as below:

```
<solr>

  <solrcloud>

    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>

    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>

    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
    <str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkACLProvider}</str>

  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>
<metrics>
  <reporter name="ganglia" group="node, jvm" class="org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrGangliaReporter">
    <str name="host">Ganglia IP</str>
    <int name="port">8649</int>
    <int name="period">60</int>
    <str name="prefix">solr</str>
  </reporter>
</metrics>

</solr>
```

Now I am trying restart Solr service it sis throwing below error:

```
ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/acplt/oncrpc/XdrEncodingStream
    at info.ganglia.gmetric4j.gmetric.GMetric.<init>(GMetric.java:82)
    at info.ganglia.gmetric4j.gmetric.GMetric.<init>(GMetric.java:58)
    at info.ganglia.gmetric4j.gmetric.GMetric.<init>(GMetric.java:40)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrGangliaReporter.lambda$start$0(SolrGangliaReporter.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.ReporterClientCache.getOrCreate(ReporterClientCache.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrGangliaReporter.start(SolrGangliaReporter.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrGangliaReporter.validate(SolrGangliaReporter.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.SolrMetricReporter.init(SolrMetricReporter.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.SolrMetricManager.loadReporter(SolrMetricManager.java:757)
    at org.apache.solr.metrics.SolrMetricManager.loadReporters(SolrMetricManager.java:728)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:508)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1516)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.acplt.oncrpc.XdrEncodingStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
```

Solr Version :6.6
Operating System : Ubuntu 16.04

I have spent considerable amount of time in  googling this error but din't get the solution for it

Comment: Do the expected `.jar` files load when you're starting Solr? The startup log should list those that are being loaded.

Comment: I dont know why oncrpc-1.0.7.jar was not present in my solr setup. I downloaded and copied it to server/lib folder. now everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed :)

Solution :
We need to deploy [oncrpc-1.0.7.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/acplt/oncrpc/1.0.7/oncrpc-1.0.7.jar) at [SolrHome]/server/lib

this will resolve above mentioned issue. 
Happy Coding